# Unable to connect Node app hosted on Heroku with MongoDB Cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am making NodeJS app hosted on heroku and using MongoDB atlas as a backend.When i am sending POST request to app via POSTMAN it is showing:

```
 Error: 503 service unavailable
```

In my opinion node app is failed to connect with MongoDB atlas cluster.If so then how can i connect it with MongoDB.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

See [Connecting Heroku App to Atlas MongoDB Cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159175/connecting-heroku-app-to-atlas-mongodb-cloud-service), you need to either connect via SSL or whitelist the relevant Heroku IP address ranges for your app.