# Facing issues in loading mongo database and frontend app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I'm working on creating an anonymous discussion forum where I've deployed my MongoDB on MongoDB Atlas (cloud platform) using Heroku. The whole app is developed using React. Here is my code for `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var models = require('./api/models/message');

var routes = require('./api/routes/routes');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var app = express();
var Message = mongoose.model('Message')

// Uncomment this line to run it on development mode (localhost) -- discussion is our db name //
// mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/discussion');

// This line is working on production mode //
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0-xucmg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

routes(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("frontend/build"));
  console.log("production");
}

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/build', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

My database name is `discussion`. When this line is uncommented:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/discussion');
```

The database loads fine and frontend code also works fine on localhost.

But I'm trying to host my database on the cloud (to resolve issues with Heroku build) with this line:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0-xucmg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
```

I'm not sure why because of this line the frontend part is not being loaded (on Heroku deployment link). I assume maybe this is because of database not being loaded. But, it'll be a great help if anyone can help me figure out this issue. I tried to follow this solution: [Connecting Heroku App to Atlas MongoDB Cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159175/connecting-heroku-app-to-atlas-mongodb-cloud-service) by providing whitelist access but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating the mongoose dependency version >= 5.0.0

Even after adding CIDR as `0.0.0.0/0` in IP whitelist in MongoDB Atlas, updating mongoose version will help to overcome this type of issue.