# Strapi deployed to Heroku is crashing in production?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, strapi

I've got an app where the frontend is deployed to Netlify and the Strapi backend is deployed to Heroku. I recently upgraded Strapi from v3.0.6 to v3.1.3. I was previously using PostgresQL in production, so along with the Strapi upgrade I also am attempting to move over to MongoDB.

I'm attempting to deploy my backend to production, however I keep receiving a 503 error and the app crashes. You can see from the error logs below that there is an issue connecting to the Mongo database.

Here are my relevant logs from Heroku:

```
2020-08-06T15:06:49.848463+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-06T15:06:49.848464+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2020-08-06T15:06:49.848465+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-06T15:06:52.238840+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-08-06T15:06:52.238869+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2020-08-06T15:06:52.239130+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-08-06T15:06:52.239199+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-08-06T15:06:52.239276+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-08-06T15:07:10.279519+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=<app-name>.herokuapp.com request_id=9e81f113-1003-42f7-82e7-59296dc1f0f8 fwd="24.19.220.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-06T15:07:22.242572+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-06T15:07:22.241Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-08-06T15:07:22.243944+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-06T15:07:22.243Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
2020-08-06T15:07:22.266318+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-06T15:07:22.266611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-06T15:07:22.269156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@0.1.0 start: `strapi start`
2020-08-06T15:07:22.269330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-06T15:07:22.269513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-06T15:07:22.269976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@0.1.0 start script.
2020-08-06T15:07:22.270129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-06T15:07:22.278069+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-06T15:07:22.278314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-06T15:07:22.278417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-06T15_07_22_271Z-debug.log
2020-08-06T15:07:22.355748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-06T15:07:22.394507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-06T15:07:23.802505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<app-name>.herokuapp.com request_id=f5876daf-f945-46b8-88c0-08a61106cfc5 fwd="24.19.220.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've got the Mongo URI env variable set in Heroku and the app runs fine locally. I'm using Mongo Atlas in the free tier, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it? Does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I spent 24 hours attempting to fix it before making this post, and just like that - a half hour after making this post - I fixed it, thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159175/connecting-heroku-app-to-atlas-mongodb-cloud-service). I needed to whitelist the IP address in order to allow the connection between MongoDB and Heroku!