# How to whitelist Heroku IP Address on MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to connect my Heroku App, written in node.js, to a cluster hosted at Atlas MongoDB Cloud.

When running my api locally in my machine I can access the database with no problem using my current IP Address. I'm also able to connect to the cluster using mongo shell.

However, when running the App in Heroku, the connection cannot be established. In the Browser JS console,In heroku, I get the error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

I also try using some add-ons on Heroku like Fixie and Fixie Socks to get an Ip Address, still giving me the same Error.

**My question is what do i need to do to establish the secure connection between Heroku and MongoDB Atlas?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting Heroku App to Atlas MongoDB Cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159175/connecting-heroku-app-to-atlas-mongodb-cloud-service)

Comment: i dont want to allow access for anwhere for scurity propose, and it a production base application

Comment: Good practice!  One of the answers to my linked question mentions the [IP address ranges in use at Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-add-heroku-dynos-to-our-allowlist-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku) and various approaches to using them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a set of static IPs from which to connect to MongoDB Atlas, your options are to either use [Heroku Private Spaces](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces) or an addon which provides a SOCKS5 proxy for outbound connections. As of this writing, the two addons in the Heroku Elements marketplace that do this are [Fixie Socks](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie-socks) and [QuotaGuard Static](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic).

Whichever addon you choose, you can connect through their SOCKS5 proxy by providing an `options` object to `mongoose.connect`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fixieData = process.env.FIXIE_SOCKS_HOST.split(new RegExp('[/(:\\/@/]+'));

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    {
      proxyUsername: fixieData[0],
      proxyPassword: fixieData[1],
      proxyHost: fixieData[2],
      proxyPort: fixieData[3]
     },
    (error) => {
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Connected to database');
      }
    }
);
```

Both addons also offer binaries which allow you to connect from libraries that don't natively support SOCKS5 proxies ([fixie-wrench](https://usefixie.com/documentation/fixie-wrench/) and [QGTunnel](https://support.quotaguard.com/support/solutions/articles/5000013939-socks-quick-start-guide-quotaguard-static)), but these should be unnecessary for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 0.0.0.0/0 ip address. it worked for me !
because this is setting to mongoDB Atlas that you allow ip address from any client or you can get your heroku ipaddress by follow this link
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.